# JQUERY functions not working with AJAX content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 drop down selectors using AJAX (first is populated, after selection the second gets populated and so on..), after selection a script is called to fill a `<p>` tag with a table that includes pictures, the problem is that I cannot use jquery plugins on those pictures (lightroom, tooltip). I can use these features if I get pictures witought AJAX. I also tryed to move the ajax script in the root (so it can recognize functions in the js files)...

[image: if i click on a category(not AJAX) (it gets populated with images) everything works fine]

Any ideas would be appreciated :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) over `.live()`, the latter has a lot of disadvantages and its use is not really encouraged nowadays. Since you are a jQuery-newbie (as you stated), if you familiarize yourself with `.delegate()` you will never miss `.live()`.

[Why You Should Never Use jQuery Live](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live)